# Customizing NSOpenPanel with iCloud UI

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, icloud, nsopenpanel

I'm using iCloud to store documents. So when user selects "Open file…" NSOpenPanel with iCloud UI is displayed. It contains "New document" button, but my app is registered as viewer for that extension. How can I customize NSOpenPanel to hide this button. I didn't find any api for this. Apple Preview doesn't show "New document" button for example…